# What does /// <reference path="jquery-1.8.3.js" /> actually do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio

I see this line of code in some of the JavaScript Files I work with, at the very top of the file ( first line ), but its not clear to me exactly what this does.

Google wasn't much help on this.

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.8.3.js" />
```

What is the purpose of it?

*To add more details, I am using Visual Studio 2015.*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is most likely for Visual Studio's JavaScript intellisense. Mads Kristensen has a nice [article](http://madskristensen.net/post/the-story-behind-_referencesjs) you can read to learn more about the history of this and how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 8):

That is a [triple-slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) for the Typescript compiler. Since `tsc` will happily compile JS as well, this should work in either language and will reference a dependency.

The `/// <reference .../>` directive shows a dependency (for compiler symbols) without necessarily importing and actually loading the file. That is useful when you have a large library (like React) that exports a lot of interfaces or `type` symbols, but you don't want to actually include (since they might be vendored at runtime). From the docs:

> The ///  directive is the most common of this group. It serves as a declaration of dependency between files.
>
> Triple-slash references instruct the compiler to include additional files in the compilation process.

Comment: Could also be for Visual Studio intellisense. I guess this depends on whether or not the OP is using Visual Studio and/or TypeScript.

Comment: It's not exclusive to TS.  Visual Studio was using it to provide IntelliSense in JavaScript even before TypeScript was a thing.