# Function from external file is undefined when called from other external file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 external files, one is called StorageBinJS.js and the other is Req1JS. My StorageBinJS contains this

```
function StorageBin() { };


StorageBin.Keys = function (key, value) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

StorageBin.Get = function (key) {
    var result = localStorage.getItem(key);
    return result;
}
```

and my Req1JS file contains

```
/// <reference path="../Storage/StorageBinJS.js" />

$(document).ready(function () {

    FruitsList();
    Quantities();

    $('#btnSave').on('click', function () {
        var fruitText = $('#ddFruits').data("kendoDropDownList");

        switch (fruitText.text()) {
            case "Apples": {
                soldData.Apples.push({ FruitName: fruitText.text(), Qty: $('#Qty').val(), Price: $('#txtCost').val() });
                StorageBin.Keys("Apples", soldData.Apples);
            } break;
            case "Bananas": {
                soldData.Bananas.push({ FruitName: fruitText.text(), Qty: $('#Qty').val(), Price: $('#txtCost').val() });
                StorageBin.Keys("Bananas", soldData.Bananas);
            } break;
            case "Oranges": {
                soldData.Oranges.push({ FruitName: fruitText.text(), Qty: $('#Qty').val(), Price: $('#txtCost').val() });
                StorageBin.Keys("Oranges", soldData.Oranges);
            } break;
            case "Pears": {
                soldData.Pears.push({ FruitName: fruitText.text(), Qty: $('#Qty').val(), Price: $('#txtCost').val() });
                StorageBin.Keys("Pears", soldData.Pears);
            } break;
            case "Watermelons": {
                soldData.Watermelons.push({ FruitName: fruitText.text(), Qty: $('#Qty').val(), Price: $('#txtCost').val() });
                StorageBin.Keys("Watermelons", soldData.Watermelons);
            } break;
            default: 0;
        }
    });
});
```

the line

> StorageBin.Keys("Apples", soldData.Apples);

Errors out saying that StorageBin is Undefined, but it looks to me like it is but I know I am wrong and not sure why it calls it as undefined when its appearing in intellisense.

Comment: This answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40726479/1911755

Comment: That explains the referencing, but not why my error is saying that StorageBin.Keys is not defined :)

Comment: It surely does.  `The /// <reference .../> directive shows a dependency (for compiler symbols) without necessarily importing and actually loading the file.`

Comment: Ah, ok. I removed the reference and same issue, or did I misinterpret something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... not sure why it calls it as undefined when its appearing in intellisense.

It appears in intellisense because of your `reference` definition, but `reference` does not actually load the file.

You need to instead `import` or `require` the file.

Comment: I just did that by using $.getScript and now it works

Comment: If you are working with a DOM and you don't want to use `import` or `require` (i.e. with TypeScript or Webpack), you can just add a `<script src="..."></script>` tag to import `StorageBinJS.js`