# Include a JS file directly in another?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Let's say I have two JS files, which are both obviously representative of larger files. The first is `root/foo.js`:

```js
let foo = true;
```

The next is `root/foopolice.js`. This code depends on `root/foo.js`, and by itself, it throws an error:

```js
function patrol(){
  if (foo) alert("Found foo"); // ReferenceError
```

Finally, there is `root/index.html`, which links the two:

```html
<script src="/foo.js"></script>
<script src="/foopolice.js"></script>
<button onclick="patrol()">Patrol for foo</button>
```

The question is, how would I "include" the variable defined in `root/foo.js` directly into `root/foopolice.js` without combining the two into one? The use of both script tags is not enough, because `root/foopolice.js` would still warn of a nonexistent error while I edit it. I'm open to solutions using JQuery or just vanilla JS, depending on best practice.

Comment: Editor warnings are completely different than execution problems. Using properly scoped variables across multiple files is a very common practice

Comment: Update: I've found that I can simply use $.getScript(script) to import the script, but no amount of jQuery can make Glitch smart.

Comment: Will depend on your editor.  For visual studio, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726454/what-does-reference-path-jquery-1-8-3-js-actually-do)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, a build process is used to create a JS bundle that would extract and combine all of the required code from multiple files (see [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) or [ESBuild](https://esbuild.github.io/)).

Without a build process, modern [JS modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) (also known as "ES modules") could be imported using `<script type="module">`. JQuery can be avoided entirely in 2020 and beyond.

**library.js**

```
const name = 'Jane Doe'

export {
  name
}
```

**main.js**

```
import { name } from './library.js'

function sayHello() {
  console.log(`hello ${name}!`)
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', sayHello)
})
```

**index.html**

```html
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>

<button>Say Hello</button>
```